# is there a way to pass the id of th eitem clicked in this function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass the id of the elements clicked in here, so when the button is clicked it should detect the id of the element clicked and then pass it to the onclick function:

```
  {finalResult.map((result) => {
    if(user.get("username") === result.author.username) {
        return <div class="central-meta item" key={result.id}>
        <div class="pit-post">
            <figure>
                <img src="images/resources/red-post2.jpg" alt="" />
                <i class="fa fa-video"></i>
            </figure>
            <div class="pit-post-deta">
                <h4><a href="social-post-detail.html" title="">{result.title}</a></h4>
                <ul class="post-up-time">
                    <li>
                        <div class="usr-fig">
                            <img src="images/resources/comet-1.jpg" alt="" />
                            <a href="#" title="">p/{user.get("username")}</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Jan 12, 2020</li>
                
                        <div class="smiles-bunch">
                            <i class="em em---1"></i>
                            <i class="em em-smiley"></i>
                            <i class="em em-anguished"></i>
                            <i class="em em-laughing"></i>
                            <i class="em em-angry"></i>
                            <i class="em em-astonished"></i>
                            <i class="em em-blush"></i>
                            <i class="em em-disappointed"></i>
                            <i class="em em-worried"></i>
                            <i class="em em-kissing_heart"></i>
                            <i class="em em-rage"></i>
                            <i class="em em-stuck_out_tongue"></i>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="number">
                <span class="plus" key={result.id} onClick={(id) => addVotes(id)}><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></span>                                                     
                <input type="text" value="0"/>
                <span class="minus" onClick={() => decreaseVotes()}><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    } else {
        console.log("none")
    }
                    
})}
```

Here is the onclick function, with this, the data which is the place where I store the database should detect the id, but this doesn't work properly:

```
const addVotes = (id) => {
    setClicked(true);
    data[id].set("votes", votes+1)



    data[id].save()
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `onClick={() => addVotes(result.id)}`

Comment: @epascarello but then it gives error when I try to pass the result.id in addVotes function

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
<span class="plus" key={result.id} onClick={addVotes}>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
</span>
```

and addVotes function

```
const addVotes=(param)=>{
    const idAttr = param.currentTarget.id; // or something else attr

    console.log(idAttr);
}
```

Comment: Putting a `key` on a react element does not set the dom element `id` attribute